# How to get data from nested TYPE object using User defined datatype in wso2dss

Tags: java, wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I am trying to retrieve data using user defined datatype(UDT) in wso2dss from oracle TYPE object, partially it's working and getting data from it. 
However when I configured nested TYPE object of Array then it stop working, it might be mapping issue.

**Scenario:** I have created 4 TYPE object which is mixed of normal object and Array object, trying to access using a funtion which return myType4 object. Futhermore without Array everything is working fine but when it comes to 
Array, it isn't working using index in wso2dss. we could only access UDT object using index values, same I used.

ERROR:

```
<faultstring>
DS Fault Message: Error in 'SQLQuery.processStoredProcQuery': DS Fault Message: The array 'myArray1' does not exist DS Code: UNKNOWN_ERROR DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR Source Data Service:- Name: Details Location: /details.dbs Description: N/A Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice Current Request Name: _getData Current Params: {} Nested Exception:- DS Fault Message: The array 'myArray1' does not exist DS Code: UNKNOWN_ERROR
</faultstring>
```

SQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE myType1 IS OBJECT (col1 VARCHAR2(100 CHAR) ,col2 VARCHAR2(2000 CHAR));
    CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE myType2 IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(1000);
    CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE myType3 IS TABLE OF myType1;
    CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE myType4 is OBJECT(
    col11 VARCHAR2(50),
    col12 myType3,
    col13 myType2);

    CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE myPackage IS
        FUNCTION getData RETURN myType4;
    end myPackage;
```

WSO2DSS DBS file:

```
<data enableBoxcarring="true" name="Data" serviceNamespace="">
<config enableOData="false" id="MYCONFIG">
<property name="carbon_datasource_name">MYCONFIG</property>
</config>
<query id="qDetails" useConfig="MYCONFIG">
<sql>
{call ?:=myPackage.getData();}
</sql>
<result element="MYDetailResponse" rowName="Details">
<element column="MY_T[0]" name="data1" xsdType="string"/> 
<element arrayName="myArray1" column="MY_T[1]" name="datalist1" /> 
<element arrayName="myArray2" column="MY_T[2]" name="datalist2"/>
</result>
<param name="MY_T" ordinal="1" sqlType="STRUCT" structType="MYTYPE4" type="OUT"/>
</query>
<resource method="GET" path="data">
<call-query href="qDetails"/>
</resource>
</data>
```

Please advise?

Answer (score 0):

I checked with WSO2 team, DSS won't support such kind of scenario, however you could use cursor for complex object of list type to get your data